# Union of perfect matchings in bridgeless cubic graphs

Tags: graph-theory

It's known that every cubic bridgeless graph has 1-factor ([Petersen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem)). But Does anybody know, how to prove that for every edge in a cubic bridgeless graph there exists a 1-factor, which contains it?

Because I found articles, where this is stated, but no proof of it so far (for example this [one](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/file/RIMS1731.pdf) - theorem 2.1.)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Petersen's theorem: A bridgeless cubic graph contains a one-factor.
This has been generalized by T. Schönberger [T. Schönberger, "Ein Beweis des Peterschen Graphensatzes" Acta Sci. Math. Szeged , 7 (1934) pp. 51–57], who proved that every edge of a bridgeless cubic graph lies in a one-factor.

Best regards,
                 Július Korbaš

Comment: unfortunately, it's a german article :( but thanks

Comment: ok I found an english source proving this: [link](http://books.google.sk/books?id=240QO32GJOcC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=bridgeless+cubic+graph+with+one+edge&source=bl&ots=0cf_0spD4j&sig=ZpoV4iNl3G4OjMk72kQ2ie-wrPI&hl=sk&sa=X&ei=q1t1UoPJCYqnhAfV4oGoBg&ved=0CJIBEOgBMAk4Cg#v=onepage&q=bridgeless%20cubic%20graph%20with%20one%20edge&f=false)